# How to find the smallest number in a text file (Python 2.5)

Tags: python

So far, my code finds the largest number in a text file but it doesn't find the smallest number, when it's run the smallest number is still 0 while the largest is 9997.

```
    integers = open('numbers.txt', 'r') # opens numbers.txt

largestInt = 0 # making variables to store the largest/smallest int
smallestInt = 0

# loop where we check every line for largest/smallest int
for line in integers:
    while largestInt <= line.strip():
        largestInt = line
    while smallestInt >= line.strip():
        smallestInt = line

# print results
print "Smallest = ", smallestInt
print "Largest = ", largestInt
```

`numbers.txt` looks like:

```
6037
-2228
8712
-5951
9485
8354
1467
8089
559
9439
-4274
9278
-813
1156
-7528
1843
-9329
574
```

and so on.

What's wrong here? If I'm doing something wrong, or the logic is incorrect please correct me.

`EDIT`

I'd like to say thanks to @Martijn Pieters and @Gexos for for explaining what I'm doing wrong. I understand why my code works now!

Final Code:

```
integers = open('numbers.txt', 'r') # opens numbers.txt

largestInt = 0 # making variables to store the largest/smallest int
smallestInt = 0

# loop where we check every line for largest/smallest int
for line in integers:
    if largestInt <= int(line.strip()): # converted a string into an int
        largestInt = int(line.strip()) # made that int into largestInt
    if smallestInt >= int(line.strip()): # converted a string into an int
        smallestInt = int(line.strip()) # made that int into smallestInt

integers.close() # closes the file

# print results
print "Smallest = ", smallestInt
print "Largest = ", largestInt
```

Results

```
Smallest =  -9993
Largest =  9997
```

Comment: Try increasing smallestInt on like 10**10

Comment: each line is a *string*, you're comparing each one *lexicographically*.  use `int(line)` to compare them as numbers.

Comment: Even if you cast your lines to int, your code will not work if the smallest number is higher than 0.

Comment: Also see [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577916-fast-minmax-function/) recipe that will make your code even more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not integers; turn your line into an integer before comparing:

```
largestInt = float('-inf')
smallestInt = float('inf')

for line in integers:
    number = int(line)
    if largestInt < number:
        largestInt = number
    if smallestInt > number:
        smallestInt = number
```

Note that you want to use `if` here, not `while`; the latter creates a loop.

I started `largestInt` and `smallestInt` with `float('-inf')` and `float('inf')`, respectively, numbers guaranteed to be smaller and larger than anything else. This makes the first time you test for `largestInt < number` *always* true, whatever number is on the first line.

Comparing strings is done lexicographically, where characters are compared one by one; `10` is smaller than `2` because `1` sorts before `2`.

You could use the `max()` and `min()` built-in functions for ease, but it'll be a bit less efficient because internally these functions do loops as well:

```
numbers = {int(line) for line in integers}
largestInt = max(numbers)
smallestInt = min(numbers)
```

Comment: You certainly want `largestInt = number`, not `largestInt = line`.  The former will result in a `TypeError` in python 3 and is a subtle bug in python 2.

Comment: I would like to add that using `0` as the initial value for the smallest number is not exactly a good idea, unless you're 100% sure there are negative numbers in the file. For every other case you can use `float("infinity")` which is guaranteed to be bigger than any integer in Python.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters  for explaining what I'm doing wrong. I understand why my code works now! Gexos answer helped a lot too, like the answers did by other people. You answered first so i vote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

While I usually like solutions that use `min` and `max`, that would require two linear passes in this case, with a lot of memory overhead. Here's a method that needs one linear pass and constant memory:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as infile:
    smallest, largest = '', None
    for line in infile:
        n = int(line)
        smallest = min(n, smallest)
        largest = max(n, largest)
    print "the smallest number is", smallest
    print "the largest number is", largest
```

Comment: I like `smallest = min(n,smallest)` in lieu of the ternary expression, but ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you need to convert your lines to integers first. Additionally, your script will not output the correct minimum number if that number is bigger than zero. To fix this, set both your maximum number and minimum number to the first entry in your file. Then check all other numbers, and see if they're bigger/smaller than the current number.

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as data_file:
    num = int(next(data_file))
    min_num, max_num = num, num
    for line in data_file:
        num = int(line)
        if num > max_num:
            max_num = num
        elif num < min_num:
            min_num = num

print 'Smallest number: {}'.format(min_num)
print 'Largest number: {}'.format(max_num)
```

This can also be solved with list comprehensions:

```
nums = [int(line) for line in open('numbers.txt', 'r')]
min_num, max_num = min(nums), max(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('number.txt') as f:
    s = [int(n.strip()) for n in f]
    print min(s), max(s)
```

Comment: set(int(n) for n in f.strip())

Comment: This produces two loops though, and still compares the digits lexicographically, as strings.

Comment: You dont need to make list, when you can use just generator. [] is actualy uncessary slower. It is like set(list(...)) insted of correct set(iterator(...))

Comment: @Guy Your `.strip()` call is at the wrong place, in fact you don't need strip() with `int()`

Answer (score 0):

A few things. You need to cast the `line` into an int from a string: `int(line.strip())` currently you are comparing an int to a string. You should also cast the assignment in `largestInt = int(line.strip())` and the same for `smallestInt`.

You should not be using `while`. `while` is for looping, not for comparing. You should be using `if`.

And last but not least make sure to close the file at the end. `integers.close()`

Answer (score 0):

```
integers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
intList = [int(x) for x in integers.readlines()]
print max(intList), min(intList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not ints. You need to call the `int` function on them at some stage most likely to convert them to numbers.

This is an example of a different approach:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    integers = [int(n) for n in f.readlines()]

smallest = min(integers)
biggest = max(integers)
```

using `with` ensures the file is auto closed after the list comprehension, which is good practice. The list comprehension results in:

```
[6037, -2228, 8712, -5951, 9485, 8354, 1467, 8089, 559, 9439, -4274, 9278, -813, 1156, -7528, 1843, -9329, 574]
```

Then `min` and `max` are called on that list.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note when setting your smallestInt to 0.  If the smallest number your text document contains is 1 then you'll still end up with a 0 as an answer.